# Загрузка ядра с сырых секторов харда

Tags: grub, qemu

Я хочу запустить `multiboot2` ядро в `qemu`, которое я посылаю как `-hda kernel.elf`.

Какие команды необходимы в грабе, чтобы запустить ядро?

Comment: А на граб разве нету мануала? Почитайте  `man grub`, почитайте топ 10 гугла, например вот http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/grub

Comment: Я их то как раз и читал, не нашел никакого способа